# How to pass views arguments into entity reference field programmatically?

Tags: 8, entities

I need to understand how i can pass a special argument into a field entity reference filtred by a View to show specifics results. My view use contextual filter.
My problem and how to anticipate the total number of items (references added with the button "Add an other element") , and to pass my argument with each new addition.

I can do it with limited number of items like that:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'node_page_edit_form':

        $form['field_references']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#selection_settings']['view']['arguments'][] = $special_arg_id;
        $form['field_references']['widget'][1]['target_id']['#selection_settings']['view']['arguments'][] = $special_arg_id;
        $form['field_references']['widget'][2]['target_id']['#selection_settings']['view']['arguments'][] = $special_arg_id;
        $form['field_references']['widget'][3]['target_id']['#selection_settings']['view']['arguments'][] = $special_arg_id;
        $form['field_references']['widget'][4]['target_id']['#selection_settings']['view']['arguments'][] = $special_arg_id;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `how to anticipate the total number of items` of what?

Comment: to anticipate the total number of items of references added with the button "Add an other element"

Comment: You can use tokens to pass the argument to the field which is an entity reference field

Comment: I know, my argument is dependent on the value of a previous field, it is for this reason that I go through `form_alter` to add my argument programmatically.